# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration on c# web browser

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am trying to integrate Facebook authentication into my Windows desktop application using `Facebook C# SDK`. I tried to have user login using Facebook with a `WebBrowser` in an area of my application window. The `WebBrowser` will always show Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

What URL should I give to my `App Setting`? Because my application will not be on a web page and Facebook App Setting does not have Windows Desktop platform.

```
private Uri GenerateFBLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
    {
        // reference: "http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-writing-your-first-facebook-application-v6"
        // var parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>
        // parameters["client_id"] = appId;
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.client_id = appID;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        // The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
        parameters.response_type = "token";

        // list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
        parameters.display = "popup";

        // add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
            parameters.scope = extendedPermissions;

        // generate the login url
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        return fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }

    private void FacebookLogin()
    {
        loginUrl = GenerateFBLoginUrl(appID, "id");

        this.FBLogin.Navigate(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this but I have two suggestions:  1) if you pass a null string what happens?  and 2) pass a arbitrary URL. Good luck.